# Slow loading of front end (public site) forms (profiles)

Tags: forms, performance

I'm experiencing slow loading times of civicrm forms at public site. For example, the form for bulletin suscribe takes about 20-30 seconds to load.

You can check this here: http://londres38.cl/1937/w3-article-90987.html

I've discarded the possibilty that there is hosting or page problems because at backend the site works flowesly with reasonable load times.

Any idea of what problem may be are causing this slow loads?

I'm using civicrm last version at civihosting, so i think there is not a install/hosting

Answer (score 1):

It seems to fail to load all sorts of *.js and *.css files inside your iframe.

[image: Firefox network analysis]

Comment: Thanks! 

What do you think can be causing this issue?
Any recommendation to solve it?